# Selenium in Powershell does not work correctly in Start-Job

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, start-job

I am trying to execute PowerShell script with Selemiun using Start-Job

```
Start-Job {
    $Url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
    $Driver = Start-SeChrome
    Enter-SeUrl -Url $Url  -Driver $Driver
    }
```

The script should open Chrome and follow the link.
Instead, it just opens Chrome.

Everything works correctly without Start-Job.
The only thing I noticed is the lack of a command prompt window with chromedriver.exe running. But judging by the Task Manager, chromedriver.exe starts up

Finding a solution is complicated by the fact that I do not know how to read the errors that occur when starting Start-job.

Comment: try use runspaces... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/

Comment: the scriptblock runs in its own scope. you need to pass the info into the scriptblock. [*grin*] take a look at `Get-Help Start-Job -Parameter InitializationScript`, at `Get-Help Start-Job -Parameter ArgumentList`, and finally at `Get-Help about_Scopes` ... especially the section titled `The Using scope modifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4568320/avshalom) for the tip.
Validly using [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module solved my problem.
Selenium is finally working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It would also work with start-threadjob or foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7.  You can download the Threadjob module in powershell 5.1